# Why can I not run properly the starting project executable, created with cmake an mingw in CLion, from the command line?

Tags: c++, mingw, clion

This is a request for an explanation, rather than a request for the solution. I do have a solution already, which is adding the following line to CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -static-libstdc++")
```

I think I understand what this implies: the compiler is not linking with the C++ standard library IO functions, or perhaps it is building an executable that needs to link dynamically to some dll, and when you run it from the command line it will not work as expected.

However, when you try to run the executable in the command line, it looks as if everything is fine! In fact, you can even trigger the creation of an output file if you use `<fstream>`. Except the output file will be empty, regardless of what you write in it. That is some mighty strange behavior...

For completion, here's the code I'm using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream fle;
    fle.open("out.txt");
    std::cout << "Hello, buddy!" << std::endl;
    fle << "Hello, a...gain!" << std::endl;
    fle.close();
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(Version_2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -static-libstdc++") #fix

add_executable(Version_2 main.cpp)
```